# nginx maintenance page for Docker based Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, docker, docker-compose, continuous-deployment

I think I have a chicken-and-egg situation:

My Rails app is Docker based and I have several images for nginx, Rails, a Resque worker, Redis and MySQL.

My current implementation of deployment is (simplistically):

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose down
... compile assets
... migrate
docker-compose up
```

Which works great, but of course if I browse to the app during deployment I don't any response which isn't great user experience.

I know of setting a 'maintenance' page in nginx that is served while the site is in maintenance mode, but the nginx image is part of the docker-compose spec, so that will go down as well.

Having all the images in one docker-compose spec does make deployment easier - if anything changes in *any* image (including nginx), that will be deployed automatically. And especially because nginx, Rails, MySQL, etc. are all in the same net.

How could I keep serving a maintenance page while the app is redeploying if nginx is part of the docker-compose spec?

(If it makes a difference, I'm using gitlab and a gitlab-runner container on the host to do the deployment from the repo.)

Thanks

Comment: In your example, is the `nginx` service being redeployed because it contains the Rails assets? If you just rebuild the assets and then do `docker-compose up` (no `down`) does it still restart the `nginx` service?

Comment: @AndyShinn - actually it doesn't _contain_ the assets, it shares a volume which contains the assets.  Hmmm OK, if I don't do `docker-compose down`, then nginx is not restarted (I get bad gateway, but that's expected because the app container is down).  OK, so I'll try enabling a maintenance page around the deployment rather than taking down all containers...

Comment: @SteveFolly, I've updated my answer. Also I provide a complete example [here](https://github.com/xbx/docker-compose-nginx-maintenance-page-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a:

## NGINX maintenance page example for docker-compose

Just keep nginx in a separate container in the same docker-compose.yml and deploy as this:

```
docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate your-app-service
```

Add some logic to put the maintenance page in nginx. The nginx service won't be touched by compose.

---

Use something like this to enable a maintenance site:

Your [nginx config](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_hc_module.html):

```
upstream backend {
    server app:80;

    server maintenance:80 backup; # <-- note the backup flag
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
    }

}
```

Then in your docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    (...)
  nginx:
    (...)
  maintenance:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./maintenance.html:/usr/share/nginx/html/index.hml
      - ./maintenance.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

maintenance.conf

```
server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    server {
        listen 8080;

        location / {
            rewrite ^ /index.html break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a complete working example here: https://github.com/xbx/docker-compose-nginx-maintenance-page-example

Comment: Ooh, I like this in preference to the 'touch a file to go into maintenance mode', which _could_ potentially get out of sync. This just checks whether the backend is running and redirects accordingly.  Or perhaps a combination of both - that would let me force maintenance mode with the backend still running?

Comment: This logic has 1 second of delay in order to "realize" that the backend is running or not. So the false positives could last 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate workflow: use [Docker swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/). This let's you do the following workflow:

```
docker swarm init
docker swarm deploy -c mycomposefile.yml
docker-compose build
docker service update ...
```

That way you don't have to take the service down, swarm mode updates it for you.